# Path error with Tesseract

Tags: python-2.7, windows-7, config, tesseract

I thought I'd got Tesseract to work on my Win 7 machine:

```
from PIL import Image
import pytesseract

pytesseract.pytesseract.tesseract_cmd = 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Tesseract-OCR\\tesseract.exe'

tessdata_dir_config = '--tessdata-dir "C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Tesseract-OCR\\tessdata"'

myFile = r"D:\temp\OCR\rightness_of_rendering.tif"

print(pytesseract.image_to_string(Image.open(myFile)))
```

tesseract.exe is located in C:\Program Files (x86)\Tesseract-OCR\tesseract.exe

eng.traineddata is located in C:\Program Files (x86)\Tesseract-OCR\tessdata

The error I get is

```
D:\LearnPython>D:\LearnPython\ocr_test.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\LearnPython\ocr_test.py", line 14, in <module>
    print(pytesseract.image_to_string(Image.open(myFile)))
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pytesseract\pytesseract.py", line 125, in
image_to_string
    raise TesseractError(status, errors)
pytesseract.pytesseract.TesseractError: (1, u'Error opening data file \\Program
Files (x86)\\Tesseract-OCR\\eng.traineddata')

D:\LearnPython>
```

Which is one directory up, so I'm a little confused as how to set that up so it'll work properly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From pytesseract [github page](https://github.com/madmaze/pytesseract)

```
tessdata_dir_config = '--tessdata-dir "<replace_with_your_tessdata_dir_path>"'
# Example config: '--tessdata-dir "C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Tesseract-OCR\\tessdata"'
# It's important to add double quotes around the dir path.

pytesseract.image_to_string(image, lang='chi_sim', config=tessdata_dir_config)
```

Note that you need to provide `config=tessdata_dir_config` into your `image_to_string` call

So if you're using eng data it would be

```
print(pytesseract.image_to_string(Image.open(myFile), lang='eng', config=tessdata_dir_config))
```